# Widgets gets shifted around by surfaceview in a relative layout android

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview

[image]
I have created two joysticksview using surfaceview. I want to place a switch button shown in the yellow box in the picture. However, when I move my joystick around on my phone, the switch button would get shifted around.

My xml code for the surfaceivew are below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_v2"
tools:context="com.example.android.java.JoyStickActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <com.example.android.java.JoyStickView
        android:id="@+id/joystickLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />


    <com.example.android.java.JoyStickView
        android:id="@+id/joystickRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />

</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_marginStart="39dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout5"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/turbo_switch_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="85dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:rotation="90"
        android:scaleX="1"
        android:scaleY="0.8"
        android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
        android:track="@drawable/track" />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: set `LinearLayout` 's `layout_height` to `match_parent` may solve it..

Comment: @MeowCat2012 that didn't work, i couldn't really find anyone that has the same issue as me. Just want to make sure, does my question make sense to you?

Comment: `layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4"` But where is linearLayout4? `layout_below` means current view should be placed below the view with the given id, here you should use `@id/xxx` instead of `@+id/xxx` to refer to an already ***existing*** view. `linearLayout4` and `linearLayout5` seems not to exist. This may not solve your problem directly but at least would make things easier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped. I realize, the reason why the widgets shifts is because my "switch" widget depends on joystickview widget. I took out the lines "android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4" " in side my switch widget xml code and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a moving widget like a joystick. Make sure other layouts or widgets does not depend on the joystick widget. For example, in my switch widget xml code, I have something like `android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4`, and `linearLayout4` is the joystick layout. Therefore, when ever my joystick moves, my switch widget layout will always move as well.